# How to change IE browser logo?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

I run my application in IE Browser. Here when I enter my URL and run the application I want to display any other logo instead of IE logo. [image]

Here, Instead of this IE logo I want to display some other. How can I do this? This is only for when I will open my URL. In other cases want to display the default IE logo only. Please help me for do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is called favicon. The favicon (also called ‘favorites icon’ or 'site icon'), is a small image displayed next to the website URL in the browser address bar, and inside the Favorites (Bookmarks) menu.

To use it put 
`<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">` inside the `<head> </head>` tag of your html file. Create the favicon image, with approximate size 16 x 16 px with this name: "favicon.ico" in the root directory of your site (There are online tools for converting your image to "ico" format).
If you have png file you can also put it:
`<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>`

Comment: @sathishkumar :) I mean, in stackoverflow you can upvote the answer, and you can mark the answer as "accepted answer" by pressing "tick" under upvote-downvote arrows )

Answer (score 1):

Download the favicon image from the site. save it in your image folder. And include it in path like below within `<head>` section.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/image_Fevicon.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

Favicon image size is 16x16 or 32x32.

you can include favicon image by using following syntax. Save your image in images folder and include path in "href".

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/image_Fevicon.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can include favicon image by using following syntax. Save your image in images folder and include path in "href".

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/image_Fevicon.jpg">
```